# Minimal BASH-like on LUKS-encrypted install after format of secondary SSD

Tags: boot, grubrescue, luks

I can't load ubuntu after I formatted the old SSD I used to have Windows on and that I thought had nothing to do with Ubuntu's boot. The Ubuntu partition is LUKS encrypted and in GRUB I am able to list the following (only the 1TB disk I have ubuntu on is connected as I disconnected the old one):

```
grub>ls
(proc) (memdisk) (hd0) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)
```

Using ls on the partitions i get the following:

```
Device hd0: No known filesystem detected - Sector size 512 byte - Total size 976762584 KiB
```

GPT1:

```
Partition hd0,gpt1: Filesystem type fat, UUID ______ - Partition start at 1024KiB - Total size 524288 KiB
```

(hd0,gpt1)/ contains a **efi/** folder, which contains **ubuntu/** and **Boot/**. ubuntu/ has a *grubx64.efi* file in it, while Boot/ contains *bootx64.efi.grb* and *bootx64.efi*

GPT2:

```
Partition hd0,gpt2: Filesystem type ext*, Last modification time _____ UUID ______ - Partition start at 525312 KiB - Total size 1750016 KiB
```

(hd0,gpt2)/ contains:

**lost+found/** (empty), **efi/** (empty), **grub/**

and a lot of linux files which from other guides i tried to look online seem important to restore the boot such as:
*vmlinuz-6.2.0-20-generic*, *initrd.img-6.2.0-20-generic*, *vmlinuz*, *initrd.img*, and others.

GPT3:

```
Partition hd0,gpt3: No known filesystem detected - Partition start at 2275328KiB - Total size 974486528 KiB
```

I tried the following:

```
>set root=(hd0,gpt2)
>set prefix=(hd0,gpt2)/
>linuxefi /vmlinuz-6.2.0-20-generic
>initrdefi /initrd.img-6.2.0-20-generic
>boot
```

And it seems like it starts (black screen with waterfall of white text) while it always gets stuck at

```
[1.8xxxxx] i915 0000:00:02.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
```

Do I have to once again bulldozer the system and reinstall everything or am I missing something? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Using [this guide](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/grub-rescue), in particular the "Via Live Image" part:

1. created a live Ubuntu USB, booted into it via "Try Ubuntu".
2. installed boot repair:

   ```bash
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair 
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install boot-repair
   ```
3. Using "Disks" I mounted the unmounted partitions of my disk and **unlocked the encrypted data partition** (Boot-repair could not fix the problem before doing such)
4. Launched boot-repair and followed its instructions to restore the boot

I will leave this question/answer here as I couldn't find any guide specifically for the scenario I was in, hoping this will be helpful to someone in the future. Boot-repair is a great tool!